# How do I deploy a runnable jar in Amazon AWS?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jar, amazon-ec2, executable-jar

I have an android client who sends a sentence to the server. Now this server does some processing and sends the string back to the Android client. I'm using basic client server communication for this, and it is working fine on the local machine. Now I want my server code to be deployed on a server so that I can provide that server address to my client code. The server is not a web app, it's a simple core Java project. As far as I understand, I'll have to deploy it as a runnable jar. But how do I do that using AWS?

Answer (score 0):

Set up [apache tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org) and use [the deployment endpoint](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Deploy_a_Directory_or_WAR_by_URL), namely `/manager/text/deploy?path=/footoo&war=file:/path/to/foo.war` to deploy the war.

If you'd rather deploy a runnable jar, set up an instance, install java on it, and put the jar onto said instance, before going in and using `java -jar runnable-foo.jar` in a [screen session](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/).

Comment: How to install Java on an instance in AWS? I'm running EC2 instance.

Comment: Are you running a Windows or Linux instance?